# Will AI in civilization 5 buy units?

Tags: civilization-5

Does the AI ever purchase units, land, or buildings?

Will an AI make use of excess gold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **YES**. Based on my experience, AI's are buying units specially when they are surrounded(usually the Capital) or about to lose a war.

There are instances that an aggressive civilizations are buying units when they declare a war against other civilization.